# Why is my RegExp failing IP server search

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to solve this problem:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/515decfd9dcfc23bb6000006/train/javascript

Write an algorithm that will identify valid IPv4 addresses in dot-decimal format. IPs should be considered valid if they consist of four octets, with values between 0 and 255, inclusive.

Note that leading zeros (e.g. 01.02.03.04) are considered invalid.

Good:
1.2.3.4

Bad: 
1.2.3
256.1.1.1
a11/.1.1.

My solution passes 331 tests, fails 6 but I don't know why.

```
function isValidIP(str) {
  if(str.length === 0) return false;
  let newReg1 = new RegExp(/^0\.0\.0\.0$/);
  let newReg = new RegExp(/^[1-9]\d{0,2}\.[1-9]\d{0,2}\.[1-9]\d{0,2}\.[1-9]\d{0,2}$/);

  let newArr = str.split('.');


  for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
    if(newArr[i] > 255)
      return false;
  }

  if(newReg.test(str) === true || newReg1.test(str) === true){
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }

}
```

And I don't know if there a way to check why they fail.

Comment: You're excluding leading zeroes, but not all of them should be. `0.0.0.0` is valid

Comment: the address containing a 0 is not considered valid e.g. 127.0.0.1 as you always expect one digit between 1-9 atleast

Comment: GOT EM : let newReg = new RegExp(/^([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)\.([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)\.([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)\.([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)$/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're excluding leading zeroes, but not all of them should be. `0.0.0.0` is valid.

Also, since you're already doing checks for the numbers, there is not really a need for regex, which will make things more complicated than they can be:

```js
function isValidIP(str) {
  const nums = str.split('.');
  const validNums = nums.every(s => ''+parseInt(s, 10) === s && s >= 0 && s <= 255);
  const validLen = nums.length === 4;

  return validNums && validLen;
}

console.log(isValidIP('1.0.0.1'));     // true
console.log(isValidIP('192.168.0.1')); // true
console.log(isValidIP('256.0.0.1'));   // false
console.log(isValidIP('01.0.0.1'));    // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you print the 6 tests that are failing ?

looks to me like newReg will not accept trailing zeroes either, despite them being valid adress numbers: 10.20.30.40 will not pass a regex which only accepts 1-9.

Comment: 10.20.30.40 will pass, but 1.0.0.1 will not

Comment: yeah that was it, fixed it. THANK YOU MAN

Answer (score 1):

`^((0|[1-9]\d{0,2})\.){3}(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}){1}$`

should work